# Same text but look different in different ide?

Tags: encode

I have text '01 - Má Lủng A' in excel and i copy to sql developer or read file excel and insert to oracle db, it became '01 - Ma' Lu'ng A'
when i copy it to compare string by javascript '01 - Má Lủng A' == '01 - Má Lủng A'(1st copied, 2nd typed)
it return false :|

Comment: It would help if you could be specific about what your question is.  That being said, you may not be using the correct data type in Oracle (or in the process of sending the query to Oracle), causing your string to be converted into plain ASCII, which will never match your original text.